# Are the Gessel sequence integers composite for all $n\ge 3$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, integer-sequences, elliptic-functions

The [Gessel sequence](https://oeis.org/A135404) is known for Ira Gessel's Lattice Path Conjecture of $2001$, which has been proved by Kauers, Koutschan and Zeilberger in $2009$ with the aid of a computer. Later, other proofs were found  ("human proofs"), e.g., by using Weierstrass elliptic functions (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.1023)).

I was wondering whether or not it is true that the integers $a_n$ of the Gessel sequence are never prime numbers for $n\ge 3$. There is an easy recursion for this sequence, namely $a(0):=1$ and 
$$
a_{n+1}=\frac{4(6n+5)(2n+1)}{(3n+5)(n+2)}a_n
$$ 
for all $n$. Is there some (obvious) reason that all $a_n$ are composite ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Towards a contradiction, suppose $n \geq 2$ is such that $a_{n+1}$ is prime.  Say, $a_{n+1}=p$.  Then, $(3n+5)(n+2)p=4(6n+5)(2n+1)a_n$.  Evidently, $p$ does not divide $a_n$ since $a_{n+1} > a_n$.  Thus, $p$ divides $6n+5$ or $2n+1$.  This implies that $6n+5 \geq p=a_{n+1}$, which is a contradiction for all $n \geq 2$.

Comment: What a coincidence a_1 and a_2 to be prime.

Answer (score 4):

It is easy to see from the recurrence that every prime factor of $a_{n}$ is less than $6n$.  But the sequence grows much faster than that.